# Google API Client ConnectionCallbackListener callback is never executed

Tags: android, google-play-services, location-services, google-client

I am using the Google Play Services to find the current location. 
But it is not going in any of the callback functions.  Google API client cannot be connected.

Here is my code of the `LocationUtil` class:

```
package com.steporganization.util;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

/**
 * Created by Yogesh on 26-07-2015.
 */
public class LocationUtil implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener{
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;
    private final static String TAG="LocationUtil_Yogesh";
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private Location location;
    private boolean isClientConnected=false;

    private Activity baseActivity;
    private Context context;

    private boolean isPlayServicesAvailable()
    {
        int resultCode= GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if (resultCode!= ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
           if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
           {
               GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,baseActivity,PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
               return false;
           }
            else
           {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
               return false;
           }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private synchronized void buildGoogleAPiClient()
    {
        client=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).
                addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).
                addApi(LocationServices.API).build();


    }

    private Location getLocation()
    {
        Location lastLocation;
        lastLocation= LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(client);
        if(lastLocation==null)
        {
            //check for location
            //requestlocation update until some location is acquired or timeout of 10 seconds
            Long initialTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
            Long finalTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            createLocationRequest();
            while(this.location==null || finalTime-initialTime<20000)
            {
                finalTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            if(this.location==null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"Unable to fetch location");
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client,this);
                return null;
            }
            else
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client,this);
                return this.location;

        }
        else
            return lastLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        Log.d(TAG,"onConnected Called");
        isClientConnected=true;
        location=getLocation();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        Log.d(TAG,"onConnection suspended Called");
        client.connect();


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onConnection Failed Called");
        Log.d(TAG, "Error Code: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

    }

    protected void createLocationRequest()
    {
        LocationRequest locationRequest=new LocationRequest().
                setInterval(1000).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.location=location;
    }





    public Location getUserCurrentLocation(Activity activity,Context context)
    {
        this.baseActivity=activity;
        this.context=context;
        if(isPlayServicesAvailable())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "play services available");
            buildGoogleAPiClient();
            if(client!=null)
            {
                client.connect();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"Cleint null");
            }
            while(isClientConnected!=true)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"connecting API client");
            }
            return this.location;

        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "play service not available");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In another activity, I am creating an object of this class and calling `getUserCurrentLocation(this,getApplicationContext())` function.

Can anybody suggest me what I am doing wrong here? 
Also, it is not correct code, but my point is why it is not reaching inside any callback functions so that I can modify my logic as per my requirements.

Also, I found a similar question, but it has not been answered yet.

Comment: Take look at my code [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bojie/locationex/MapsActivity.java), and entire project [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android). Change my code on the method `handleNewLocation(Location location)` to save the user current location. And then get the `Location` from another class.

Comment: @bjiang: Thank you for looking into my problem and code. But I want to create a Util class which does not extend any activity. If I am using the same code flow in my activity, it is working fine.

Also, one more thing I have observed. If I change 
1.)return type of function getUserCurrentLocation() from Location to void and
2.) remove isConnected check in while loop.

Same utility works fine. But still I don't know the reason for same.

Comment: I notice that you do not use any method to `getUserCurrentLocation`, you just return it.

Comment: I have called the `client.connect()` function inside `getUserCurrentLocation`. So, once it get connected, it should call the `onConnected` callback , but that is never called in my case.

Comment: I think your pass the activity and content from another class have some problem call back in this class. Maybe you check `buildGoogleAPiClient`

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the problem is being created by `while(isClientConnected!=true)` method due to which the thread is stuck here only couldnt go to callback method and it seems to be thread level problem to me.